# Django Error ---index() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pk'

Tags: python, django

I have this error when try to open a path. It requires a pk in my def and i inserted it, but still the issue is there. If someone could help, i would owe you a lot!

This is the error i have in browser:

```
TypeError at /batches/
index() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pk'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/batches/
Django Version: 1.11.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
index() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pk'
Exception Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response, line 185
Python Executable:  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6
Python Version: 3.6.1
Python Path:    
['/Users/cohen/Documents/project/sanctions',
 '/Users/cohen/Documents/project/sanctions',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python36.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyObjC']
Server time:    Mon, 24 Jul 2017 10:47:02 +0000
```

My urls in batches

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # /batches/
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),

    # /batches/2
    url(r'^(?P<batches_id>[0-9]+)/$',views.detail, name="detail"),

    # businessname/1
    url(r'^(?P<businessname_id>[0-9]+)/$',views.index_businessname, name="detail_businessname"),

    # individuals/1
    url(r'^(?P<individuals_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.index_individuals, name="detail_individuals"),
]
```

And the views:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from .models import BusinessName
from .models import Individuals
from .models import Batches

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def index(request, pk):
    all_Batches = Batches.objects.all()
    html = ''
    for batch in all_Batches:
        url = '/batches/' + str(batch.id) + '/'
        html += '<a href="#"' + url + '">' + str(batch.BatchNumber)+ '</a><br>'
    return  HttpResponse(html)

def detail(request, batch_id):
    return HttpResponse("<h2>Details for Batches ID:"  + str(batch_id) + "</h2")


def index_businessname(request):
    all_BusinessNames = BusinessName.objects.all()
    html = ''
    for bn in all_BusinessNames:
        url = '/businessname/' + str(bn.id) + '/'
        html += '<a href="#"' + url + '">' + bn.FullName + '</a><br>'
    return HttpResponse(html)

def detail_businessnames(request, bn_id):
    return HttpResponse("<h2>Details for Business Names ID:"  + str(bn_id) + "</h2")

def index_individuals(request):
    all_individuals = Individuals.objects.all()
    html = ''
    for i in all_individuals:
        url = '/individuals/' + str(i.id) + '/'
        html += '<a href="#"' + url + '">' + i.FullName + '</a><br>'
    return HttpResponse(html)


def detail_individuals(request, i_id):
    return HttpResponse("<h2>Details for Individual Names ID:"  + str(i_id)+ "</h2")
```

Thank you in advance,
Cohen

Comment: View expects `pk` to be passed from the url but your url pattern doesn't include 'pk'.

Answer (score 5):

Include `pk` in your url.

Change your url like this,

```
url(r'(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.index, name='index'),
```

instead of,

```
# /batches/

url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
```

**OR,**

if you are not passing `pk` to views then remove `pk` from `index` view as showned below.

```
def index(request):
    all_Batches = Batches.objects.all()
    html = ''
    for batch in all_Batches:
        url = '/batches/' + str(batch.id) + '/'
        html += '<a href="#"' + url + '">' + str(batch.BatchNumber)+ '</a><br>'
    return  HttpResponse(html)
```

Answer (score 3):

**There are two arguments for the index view. The URL that you have written only gives `request`. You must give `pk` as an input just like the `detail` URL**

Answer (score 1):

Your url /batches/ has no parameter. So,
Your index view should be

```
def index(request):
   # ......
```