# How to collect data from model into select tag

Tags: python, django

Model.py

```
class techgroup(models.Model):
    Technology=models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.Technology
```

views.py

```
def technology(request,id,*args, **kwargs):
    Technology = techgroup.objects.all()
    print(Technology)
    selected_item = get_object_or_404(techgroup, 
                   pk=request.POST.get('Technology_id'))
    # get the user you want (connect for example) in the var "user"
    techgroup.Technology = selected_item
    techgroup.save()
    context = {'Technology': Technology}
    return render(request, "analytics/radio.html", context)
```

url.py

```
path('technology/<int:pk>/', views.technology, name='technology'),
```

What is wrong in this code? I'm getting the following error

> technology() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'

Comment: pass id in your url
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45278718/django-error-index-missing-1-required-positional-argument-pk

Answer (score 0):

This question doesn't have anything to do with your title.

Your view is expecting an argument called `id`. But your URL is providing one called `pk`. These need to match. Change the URL:

```
path('technology/<int:id>/', ...)
```